# Does Latin allow the letter K in suffixed words?

Tags: etymology, spelling, suffixes, english

Does Latin allow the letter 'k' in suffixed words?

Actually, I'm explaining a phenomenon in which English spelling changes...

Consider the following examples:

Li**kea**ble, sha**kea**ble, ma**kea**ble - these words are of Germanic origin. They do allow 'k' in words that are suffixed.

Now,

- Revoke + able -> revocable but not revokeable/revokable.
- Invoke + able -> invocable but not invokeable/invokable.
- Provoke + able -> provocable but not provokeable/provokable.

They're from Latin revocare, invocare, provocare respectively.

It has to do with their etymologies. They're of Latin origin.

My question is: Does Latin allow the letter k in suffixed words?

Or what's the reason for this? They allow 'c' in the suffixed words but don't allow 'k'. Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does Latin allow the letter k in suffixed words?

It doesn't, because Latin doesn't allow the letter K at all.
Well, almost; there are a couple of words with K and they mostly have spelling variants with C.
In particular, the words you mention are never spelled with a K in Latin.

I have never seen K within a Latin word, only at the beginning.
(Perhaps there could be prefixes.)
The only two verbs with K are *kalare* and *kalumniari*, but they are both also spelled with C and are very rare anyway.

It seems the Latin C has turned into a K in some English words, but that change did not happen within Latin.
I don't know whether it was English or an intermediate language.
Perhaps English doesn't want C before E when it's pronounced as a K?
Follow-up questions in this direction are a better fit to the English sites or perhaps Linguistics.

Comment: Thank you, Joonas, for your quick response. *I don't know whether it was English or an intermediate language. Perhaps English doesn't want C before E when it's pronounced as a K?* -> Yes, the letter 'c' gives /s/ sound when it comes before e, i and y. On the other hand, 'c' gives /k/ sound when it comes before a, o and u. The spelling changed to 'k' in order to maintain the /k/ sound (which was original sound of the word in Latin).

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul I'm glad to be able to help! That's what I expected.